# How to use group by and multiple select string join

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, group-by

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comcom))
         {
           da.Fill(dt);
         }
var zxc = from uu in dt.AsEnumerable()
  select new dino1
   {
      UserName = uu.Field<string>("UserName"),
      Role = uu.Field<string>("Role"),
      appcode = uu.Field<string>("appcde"),
      fullname = uu.Field<string>("fullname"),
      scheduledate = uu.Field<DateTime>("Scheddte"),
      datecreated = uu.Field<DateTime>("DateCreated"),
      doctypes = uu.Field<string>("doctype"),
      trans = uu.Field<string>("transactions"),
      qqqq = uu.Field<string>("quantity"),

  };
var res1 = zxc.GroupBy(cc => cc.appcode).Select(dd => new dino1 { appcode = dd.Key, doctypes = 
           string.Join(", ", dd.Select(ee => ee.doctypes).ToList()), trans = string.Join(", ", 
           dd.Select(ee => ee.trans).ToList()), qqqq = string.Join(", ", dd.Select(ee => 
           ee.qqqq).ToList()) });

var namaewa = res1.ToList();
```

The problem is I want to add another key for GroupBy aside from appcode and another selection for it to be included at the list and displayed at my view. Is it impossible to add another key or Selection while using Model? because if i didn't use Model, it becomes anonymous type and i can add another key or selection, but the View don't accept anonymous type so i have to do it in model.

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING? Is it to get more attention? Shouting is considered to be _rude_, and therefore viewed negatively. Remember: not all attention is good.

Comment: You need to create a anonymous type for that `GroupBy`. FOr example, `zxc.GroupBy(cc => new { cc.appcode, cc.fullname})`.

Comment: originally its anonymous type, but when i transferred it at View, the list couldn't be fetched and returned an error, when i search for that, it said that i should use model so i put a model, the downside, i couldn't add another key for GroupBy and another selection without String.Join :(

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.